# Do i need a localhost server to invoke a web service

Tags: web-services

I'm very fresh and beginner in the web services world, I'm trying to learn how to deploy and consume services.

My question: Using any technology (such as Java), when I want to invoke some web service that is deployed in a remote server, do i need to install and configure a localhost server in order to access the web service? or I can access it without install server

Note: I'm asking about consuming a web service not developing a one

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Just as your web browser doesn't require a web server to access other web servers, your code doesn't require a web server to access other web servers.